# Best way to sync a table between two sql server databases with an identity key

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an SSIS package that moves data from a table into another table in another database.  The source table has an identity key.

I need to perform some operations on the data.  The only way I can see to do this is to disable the identity key in the destination table and then use the alter table switch approach outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column-sql-server.

Is there an easier way to migrate data, preserve a key and then restart the identity column?

Comment: I'm confused. Both tables have an identity key. Won't they both have the same data within the columns between each table?

Comment: No, because in the SSIS package, I can't control the order of the data insertion.  Because the destination table manages the identity key and auto increments, it assigns the wrong numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go this route:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table> ON
...
DBCC CHECKIDENT(<table>)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table> OFF
```

SET IDENTITY_INSERT:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

DBCC CHECKIDENT:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an OLE DB Destination this is handled for you via the "keep identity" check box.

See the [Fast Load Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx) section in BOL.